# Does a closed pull request on Github mean that it was not merged?

Tags: github, open-source, github-api, pull-request

Does a closed pull request on Github imply that the pull request is not merged?
If no, is there a way I can determine if a pull request which was closed was merged or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> If no, is there a way I can determine if a pull request which was closed was merged or not?

A pull request has at the top of the page it's status. There's 3 possibilties:

- open: pending, might need some change.
- closed: refused
- merged: accepted

So, if you can see `Closed` at the top, the PR hasn't been accepted: *it hasn't been merged*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So for instance in this case: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/15716. At the end the developer has added a comment saying that it was merged, however the pull request status is closed. So was the pull request merged or not finally?

Comment: The dev probably meant that those *changes* were included in `v4.4.0`, but the actual PR isn't merged.

Comment: Thanks. So would you say that this is usually how most open source projects on Github would operate and that if a pull request is closed it usually is not merged?

Comment: No. Usually, you merge the PR if it includes changes you want. And yes, if a PR is closed, it's not merged.

Comment: WRONG! My employer uses GitHub in addition to our own Git server (for historical reliability / availability / security reasons). If you rebase your feature branch but don't merge the branches in the right order locally before pushing them back up, you CAN end up with a correctly merged PR which then appears as "Closed" on GitHub but with the message "Pull request successfully merged and closed"!

Answer (score -5):

There's 3 possibilties:

open: pending

closed: refused

merged: accepted

Comment: This is dupe of existing answer.